# Remove grey background and turn it transparent

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

ImageMagick does not replace '#c0c0c0' with a transparent background

I have tried `magick convert img.png -fuzz 50% -transparent '#c0c0c0' 0.png` 
and a convert option without "magick"
running version windows 10 x64 v7.0.8-14Q16 . 
A problem for later: using a bash script to convert 200 of these and it seems imagemagick also doesn't overwrite if output name is the same

here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uneS.png

No change...

Comment: Your command works fine for me.

Comment: Your command <code>magick convert img.png -fuzz 50% -transparent '#c0c0c0' 0.png </code> works for me just fine with the file you provided. Can you run it with debug on and post output? <code>magick convert -debug 'All' img.png -fuzz 50% -transparent '#c0c0c0' -fuzz 50% -transparent '#c0c0c0' 0.png</code>

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it is just a problem with windows? Tried it on linux and it works fine.

Comment: On Windows, try removing the quotes or changing to double quotes. Also for ImageMagick 7, use magick, not magick convert and not convert. If you are running the command in a .bat file, then double the % to %%. On my Mac, running the file multiple times writes over the same output and does not create new files